# how to ue memset to set a particular column of 2D array

Tags: c++, memset

Guys i have a array xd[2][10000] like that now i
 i want to run a loop from 0 to 10000
now i want that when i=0 the value of xd array from 0 to 10000 becomes 0
next time when i=1 the value from xd[0][1] to xd[0][10000] becomes 1 similary when i=2 from xd[0][2] to xd[0][10000] becomes 2 and so on i want to use memset function for this so can u guys help me with code for it.
similary for xd[1][i] also 
One could do that easily by increasing xd[0][i]=i and xd[1][i]=i and i would get the same result but i know that i dont need that i want this for a another program so please just memset function only

Comment: dont -1 comment if u can help help it

Comment: What is the _type_ of each array element? Since `memset()` fills with __bytes__ it won't do what you want with a value other than `0` on something like `int`.

Comment: long long is the type of array

Comment: Please use proper grammar (punctuation!) and code formatting to aid comprehension.

Comment: new here so excuse me !!!!!!!!!!!:)

Comment: Then `memset()` simply won't do what you want. For example, filling with `1` you will end up with a value of `0x0101010101010101` in your `long long`.

Comment: thanks for all -1 guys:) for no reason i think -1 for my language bcz just i am new here:)

Comment: I'm not sure when they invented the "Shift" key but it's something you should check out!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    xd[0][i] = i;
```

No need for `memset`.

---

As your question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) the C++ standard library have many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), including one called [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) which will do exactly what the above does, but in even less code:

```
std::iota(std::begin(xd[0]), std::end(xd[0]), 0);
```

Comment: as i said i want to use memset function only see my post i know this method i dont need this i want it for specific program but dont want to post whole program here

Comment: @AlokSrivastava Then call `memset` only for the specific value? What you are doing is equivalent to what my code is doing, but you want to use a more ineffective method of doing it... First you set all values to zero, then you want overwrite all but one with `1`, then you want to overwrite all but two with `2` etc. That's a lot of overwrites that's not needed.

Comment: ok see in my original program i have another array i am looping it and checking it with an another value and then increasing this array in same format as i mentioned on basis of that check again inside this i am using another loop i dont want so much loops in my program. So is the method u stated faster than memset

Comment: @AlokSrivastava: This method is _correct_ which is more important than being _faster_.

Comment: @AlokSrivastava You still loop over the array, but then you call a function that in it contains a loop. That will quite obviously be less effective. It's also less obvious what your doing. My way is very straight-forward, you see exactly what it does, the effectiveness comes second.

Comment: yes thanks it should help and it will i know that :) otherwise i would use the loop method but shouldn't there be i in place of 0 in ur iota example.

Comment: @AlokSrivastava The `std::iota` call doesn't need the loop, the value is the starting value. It's equivalent to my loop version, but even more concise and to the point, and probably better optimized/optimizable as well.